# Bash Regular expression for "not space, comma, not space"

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file like this:

> a,b,c,"hello, hi",d

I want the field separator to be not space, comma, not space.
Currently I have

> cat file | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[^ ],[^ ]" } ; { print $4 }'

which should give "hello, hi" but it returns nothing. I'm quite new to this regular expression thing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh, no it should not give `hello, hi`. What actually  happens is:

```
 a,b,c,"hello, hi",d
|| ||| ||       ||_|Third fied separator
|| ||| ||_______|
|| ||| |   $3
|| |||_|
|| || Second field separator
|| ||
|| |+- $2 is a comma
||_|
| First field separator
|
+- $0 is empty
```

So after the third field separator, the line is empty. You can verify this behaviour with

```
aaa,baa,caa,"hello, hi",daa
```

as input-file.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with CSV files regularly, consider installing the csvtool, then you can simply say:

```
echo 'a,b,c,"hello, hi",d' | csvtool col 4 -
```

and it will spit out

```
"hello, hi"
```

Answer (score 1):

solution is to define the field content instead of field separator. You need to use gawk because standard awk does not have this feature natively. (on linux, awk = gawk)

```
echo 'a,b,c,"hello, hi",d' \
 | awk '
     # define the content with FPAT
     # here any non , or a encapsulate quoted content
     BEGIN{ FPAT = "[^,]*|\"[^\"]*\"" }

     # for showing each field
     {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf( "field %d: %s\n", i, $i)}
     '

field 1: a
field 2: b
field 3: c
field 4: "hello, hi"
field 5: d
```

By default, regex matching try to always take the longest possible so a "..,..." is longer than ".. and/or ..." taking full quoted string instead of partial coma separated content of the same string

Comment: Gives me a different output than what you got. https://imgur.com/a/kVPlb5q

Comment: do you have gawk ? this is the same result (as yours) when using my aix. Native awk does not have the FPAT feature

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sed`:

```
>sed 's/.*\("[^"]*"\).*/\1/' <<< 'a,b,c,"hello, hi",d'
"hello, hi"
```

or `grep`:

```
>grep -o '"[^"]*"' <<< 'a,b,c,"hello, hi",d'
"hello, hi"
```